# Pressing a button inside UICollectionViewCell affects other buttons

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to animate a button inside a `UIcollectionviewCell` when it is pressed.

I have setup my `IBAction` in my `CustomCell` class and when I click on a button inside one the cells the animation starts.

The problem here is that if I scroll the `UICollectionView` other buttons get effected from the animation. I think is a problem to refresh `indexPath` but how can I avoid this?

```
@IBAction func actionBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)
        sender.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you scroll the collection view, and new cells appear on the screen, the buttons in those views are missing or scaled up?

Comment: yes, seems that the buttons in those is reused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`, you need to reset the transform and alpha of the cell's button.

Answer (score 0):

this is the tableView reused problem, the new button state is reused by other cells, you can use a property in you tableView datasource to mark the button's state， this can make sure no reused problem happen, remember when you change a view's status in tableView cell, you should also make sure the tableView dataSouce make the corresponding record;